# Adding traces in the same subplot messes with bar size

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I've made a function to generate a Gantt chart in plotly.

```py
  def create_plot(self, date_start, date_end):
        df = self.filtered_df

        # Create a dict for every customer
        customers = df['Customer'].unique()

        # Pixels per horizontal bar
        pixel = 35

        # Create a gantt chart for every customer
        customer_plots = dict()
        heights = []
        for customer in customers:
            # filter tasks for customer
            customer_plot = df.loc[df['Customer'] == customer]

            # create timeline
            fig = timeline(customer_plot, x_start='StartDate', y='ProdName', x_end='DueDate', text='DocNum', color='Estat')
            fig.update_traces(textposition="inside")
            customer_plots[customer] = fig
            heights.append(5 + len(customer_plot)*pixel)

        # Plot them in a shared x_axis       
        fig_sub = make_subplots(rows=len(customer_plots), row_heights=heights, subplot_titles=list(customer_plots.keys()))
        fig_sub.update_xaxes(type='date')

        for i, (customer, plot) in enumerate(customer_plots.items()):
            for trace in plot['data']:
                fig_sub.add_trace(trace, row=i+1, col=1)


        fig_sub.update_layout(
            autosize=False,
            height=sum(heights),
            width=1500
        )

        for ax in fig_sub['layout']:
            if ax[:5]=='xaxis':
                fig_sub['layout'][ax]['range']=[date_start, date_end]
                fig_sub['layout'][ax]['dtick']=86400000.0*7

        
        self.plot = fig_sub
```

The function `px.timeline` returns me a tuple of traces for every different color. If there is one single color in the suplot the bars look fine (with the height I need in order to display the inside text)
[image]

But when two colors are present, I have to add another trace in the same subplot with the bars of the different colors.

```py
for i, (customer, plot) in enumerate(customer_plots.items()):
    for trace in plot['data']:
        fig_sub.add_trace(trace, row=i+1, col=1)
```

When I do so, it messes with the heights of the bars and I can't actually see the text inside:
[image]

I'd like them to look the same as the first photo. Not with extra spacing between them. How could this be accomplished?

Comment: If you could add dummy data, it would be easier for help.

Comment: Instead of adding graphs, you can process the data itself. Append the new data to the old data and then plot the graph.

Comment: without sample data it's impossible to really answer.   This looks same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578883/plotly-express-timeline-gantt-chart-color-coding-based-on-column-in-dataframe/71592761#71592761

Answer (score 0):

- this as I see it reduces to same question and this answer: [color coding gantt on column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578883/plotly-express-timeline-gantt-chart-color-coding-based-on-column-in-dataframe/71592761#71592761)
- you have not provided sample data, so have simulated some.  Also question you are asking can be reduced to a much simpler set up

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

r = np.random.RandomState(22)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Customer": np.repeat(list("ABCDE"), 20),
        "StartDate": pd.date_range("1-jan-2020", freq="W-MON", periods=100),
        "DueDate": pd.date_range("10-jan-2020", freq="W-FRI", periods=100),
        "ProdName": np.tile(["quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over"], 20),
        "DocNum": np.tile(range(8, 13), 20),
        "Estat": r.choice(list("QRSTUV"), 100),
    }
)

fig = px.timeline(
    df,
    x_start="StartDate",
    y="ProdName",
    x_end="DueDate",
    text="DocNum",
    # color="Estat",
    hover_data=["Estat"],
    facet_row="Customer",
)

# generate a color map for values to color
cmap = {
    v: c
    for v, c in zip(df["Estat"].unique(), np.tile(px.colors.qualitative.Plotly, 20))
}
# update marker colors using column 
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda t: t.update({"marker": {"color": [cmap[a] for a in t["customdata"][:, 0]]}})
)
```

1. don't use `color` **plotly express** parameter as this generates a trace per value.  Save required information into `customdata` using `hover_data` parameter
2. update all traces, set `marker_color` to an array that maps the values to a color

[image]

#### integrated

- your sample code looks like a method in a class.  Have synthesized a class and integrated the solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.express import timeline
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

class dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        r = np.random.RandomState(22)
        self.filtered_df = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "Customer": np.repeat(list("ABCDE"), 20),
                "StartDate": pd.date_range("1-jan-2020", freq="W-MON", periods=100),
                "DueDate": pd.date_range("10-jan-2020", freq="W-FRI", periods=100),
                "ProdName": np.tile(["quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over"], 20),
                "DocNum": np.tile(range(8, 13), 20),
                "Estat": r.choice(list("QRSTUV"), 100),
            }
        )

    def create_plot(self, date_start, date_end):
        df = self.filtered_df

        # Create a dict for every customer
        customers = df["Customer"].unique()

        # Pixels per horizontal bar
        pixel = 35

        # Create a gantt chart for every customer
        customer_plots = dict()
        heights = []
        for customer in customers:
            # filter tasks for customer
            customer_plot = df.loc[df["Customer"] == customer]

            # create timeline
            fig = timeline(
                customer_plot,
                x_start="StartDate",
                y="ProdName",
                x_end="DueDate",
                text="DocNum",
                hover_data=["Estat"],
            )
            fig.update_traces(textposition="inside")
            customer_plots[customer] = fig
            heights.append(5 + len(customer_plot) * pixel)

        # Plot them in a shared x_axis
        fig_sub = make_subplots(
            rows=len(customer_plots),
            row_heights=heights,
            subplot_titles=list(customer_plots.keys()),
        )
        fig_sub.update_xaxes(type="date")

        for i, (customer, plot) in enumerate(customer_plots.items()):
            for trace in plot["data"]:
                fig_sub.add_trace(trace, row=i + 1, col=1)

        fig_sub.update_layout(autosize=False, height=sum(heights), width=1500)

        for ax in fig_sub["layout"]:
            if ax[:5] == "xaxis":
                fig_sub["layout"][ax]["range"] = [date_start, date_end]
                fig_sub["layout"][ax]["dtick"] = 86400000.0 * 7

        cmap = {
            v: c
            for v, c in zip(
                df["Estat"].unique(), np.tile(px.colors.qualitative.Plotly, 20)
            )
        }
        fig_sub.for_each_trace(
            lambda t: t.update(
                {"marker": {"color": [cmap[a] for a in t["customdata"][:, 0]]}}
            )
        )
        self.plot = fig_sub


d = dummy()
d.create_plot(d.filtered_df["StartDate"].min(),d.filtered_df["DueDate"].max())
d.plot
```